# Rebuttal limited to one page

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I recently submitted to a machine learning conference, and got 3 weak accepts. One concern was, that the work may be of limited interest. Therefore I went ahead and collected more example in the literature that were related, and found a bunch of them (most very recently, so I couldnt have included them in the original submission). However, if I want to include all of them, it takes more than half of my one page limit, and I don't have enough space left to address the rest. 
How strict are these limits if it is only references that are over the one page limit?

Alternatively some of the other criticism is just typos. I could try to address them by just generally saying something like: 'Thank you for pointing out the typos, we have fixed all of them', without naming them separately. Would you recommend that, or could that be too brief for a reviewer (not acknowledging his work enough?)

Comment: If you have 3 weak accepts, in most venues that means you are generally in so long as you don't shoot yourself in the foot somehow. So don't get too carried away in over-promising!

Comment: The only time I'd mention typos individually is if I had been specifically told to do so. Otherwise, I'd just say that the typos have been fixed (and I'd double-check to be sure they really have all been fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to say much about simple things like typos. As for the other, if you go over the one page limit make sure than everything essential is on the first page. Even that is a bit risky if someone is a page limit fanatic. The best route is to say what you can in one page, mentioning only important things.

But if you think of it as a "response" rather than a "rebuttal" you won't get into an argumentative mode which won't serve you well.